# angular 2 set combobox values programatically

Tags: angular, combobox, angular2-forms

I have an issue with setting values of combobox from the component. values for comboboxes are loaded in levelCombined[j][i]['result']

```
                <tr *ngFor="let x of levelCombined, let j=index">
                <td *ngFor="let y of x, let i=index">
                    <select class="form-control" id="comboBoxLevelSelction"
                            name="levelSelection"
                            (change)="onLevelSelect($event,j,i)">
                        <option disabled selected value> - select an option -</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let ln of levelNames" [ngValue]="levelCombined[j][i]['result']">{{levelCombined[j][i]['result']}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Currently all comboboxes are set with default option. I think that I am not using ngValue properly.

Comment: you can use the property binding syntax `[value]="your value"`. More details on binding different form controls can be found here. [https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [(ngModel)] to bind the default option with value of the component.

Comment: you are right I, I used  `code`. <option selected [(ngModel)]="levelCombined[j][i]" ngDefaultControl>{{levelCombined[j][i]['level']}}</option> `code`. and it works. thanks!